# What is the add equals operator in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, outer-join

In Oracle SQL, there is an (+)= operator that adds equals.

I have been searching online but have been unable to find the equivalent for PostgreSQL syntax, does this operator exist in PostgreSQL? If not, how would I go about achieving the same functionality?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you do mean Oracle's older outer join syntax then @pifor is correct. But you didn't mention join so perhaps you have another construct in mind. Let J=1, K=3, now J+=K and J is then 4? Well there is no such operator in Postgres, just plan old J=J+K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OUTER JOIN is [documented in PostgreSQL.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)

This is also documented in [Oracle SQL Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Joins.html#GUID-29A4584C-0741-4E6A-A89B-DCFAA222994A) which says:

> Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax
>   rather than the Oracle join operator. Outer join queries that use the
>   Oracle join operator (+) are subject to the following rules and
>   restrictions, which do not apply to the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax:
>
> You cannot specify the (+) operator in a query block that also contains FROM clause join syntax.
>
> The (+) operator can appear only in the WHERE clause or, in the context of left-correlation (when specifying the TABLE clause) in the
>   FROM clause, and can be applied only to a column of a table or view.
>
> If A and B are joined by multiple join conditions, then you must use the (+) operator in all of these conditions. If you do not, then
>   Oracle Database will return only the rows resulting from a simple
>   join, but without a warning or error to advise you that you do not
>   have the results of an outer join.
>
> The (+) operator does not produce an outer join if you specify one table in the outer query and the other table in an inner query.

NB: in Oracle PL/SQL there is neither += nor +:= operator:

```
SQL> declare
  2  i numeric := 0;
  3  begin
  4   i+:=1;
  5  end;
  6  /
 i+:=1;
  *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "+" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;
The symbol "+" was ignored.


SQL> --
SQL> declare
  2  i numeric := 0;
  3  begin
  4   i+=1;
  5  end;
  6  /
 i+=1;
  *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "+" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;


SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL> --
SQL> declare
  2  i numeric := 0;
  3  begin
  4   i := i + 1;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```